# Egyptian Fraction equation in Python

Tags: python, fractions

Some sort of function that finds the standard fractional notation version of the given Egyptian fraction.

For example:

```
input: 3, 15
output: 2/5
```

explained for those not familiar with Egyptian fractions:

```
(1/3 + 1/15) = 18/45 = 2/5
```

What kind of equation could do this? if not an equation then what set of operations?

Answer (score 3):

```
from fractions import Fraction

def egyptian(a, b):
    frac = (Fraction(1.0/a) + Fraction(1.0/b)).limit_denominator()
    return frac.numerator, frac.denominator

egyptian(3, 15)
>>> (2L, 5L)
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like a math's question than a Python question, but I'll give you a few hints:

1. split your input into tokens (`str.split`)
2. parse your tokens to integers (`int(x)`)
3. apply the formula for adding fractions
4. convert to irreductible fraction (divide by gcd, you can use euclid's method)
5. profit

for adding fractions: `a/b + c/d = (ad+cb)/bd`, as `a` and `c` are 1, simplify to `(d+b)/db`

or take a look a [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) if you feel lazy about adding and reducing fractions